# Installing curl in php

Tags: php, curl, installation

I have only dev CPP in my Win7 system. I have a xampp server so how can I install Curl in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP's PHP comes with CURL as an extension, but it's not enabled by default.  You just have to look in php/php.ini for a line that reads

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

and uncomment it.